# Тег img  в CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

В отображении пишу тег `<img src='pic.jpg'>`, при запуске скрипта картинка не показывается. Как правильно картинку выводить, подскажите нубу. ))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Валентин, создайте папку в корне сайта images в неё поместите изображение.
application/views/ваш_файл.php
там указываете путь вот такой

> ```
> <img src="images/файл.png" width="ширина" height="высота">
> ```

Comment: так и сделал..не помогло..блин. Может есть какойто исходник с примером??

Comment: загрузил пример на народ - http://narod.ru/disk/22783580001/CI_example.zip.html

application/views/welcome_messages.php - там указан путь
изображение в корне.

Comment: спасибо, разобрался! а CI работает с картинками только из папки images? создаю другие - не отображает.

Comment: CI - Сам по себе странный фреймворк, особенно можно смеятся над поддержкой memcache :)

Answer (score 0):

Мб путь указан не верно? В исходном коде страницы(в браузере) гляньте какую ссылку выводит.

Comment: в исходном коде выдает вот такое
img src="pic.jpg"
тоесть тот же относительный путь что и задаю..картинку ложу в корень сайта, закидывал её и в папку application и system))нифига)

Comment: А в какой папке сам скрипт в котором выводится картинка? попробуйте так же

**/**pic.jpg

Comment: при таком пути картинка должна лежать  там же, где и исходная страница.

Comment: тоесть там где отображение??

Comment: ваш вопрос непонятен.

Comment: то я к ответу KoVadim)
скрипт лежит в папке
test.ci\www\application\views
туда пихал, тоже не работает

Comment: да, и /pic.jpg тоже не работает..

Answer (score 0):

Вдруг кому пригодиться, сам сегодня целый день бился, необходимо добавить в файл .htaccess папку с вашими картинками, а то он перенаправляет запрос, поэтому codeigniter не видит картинок